# How to get files from an old Windows PC that won't turn on to a Mac?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I've got an old Windows tower PC. I believe it was purchased circa 1998-2000 and used until 2009. The PC will not turn on. I want to see what is on the hard drive in the broken computer.

I use a Mac today.

At present the PC hard drive is still in the PC tower.

What is the best way to check the files on the hard drive of the Windows PC?

Is it to remove the hard drive from the tower and hook it up to an external USB hard drive enclosure which then connects to my Mac? If so, will my Mac be able to read the files from the hard drive of the broken PC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is your best option and yes, your mac should be able to read it just fine. The drive would most likely be formatted as FAT32 or NTFS, both of which can be read my your mac.

Note that if your hard drive is also from the 90s, it's probably not a SATA drive yet (but probably IDE) so you'll have to make sure that your hard drive enclosure supports the old-school connectors.

[image]

Another option might be to try and boot the tower from a bootable floppy disk or CD/DVD (maybe you have a Windows 95/98 disk lying around, alternatively build a Hiren CD-rom), and try and access your hard drive from there. But I would always choose to remove the hard drive if you have that enclosure - it's much less of a hassle than trying to make the old machine boot and then still having to copy over files to some other medium.

Also, you're about 18 years late with your backups :)